# Semantic HTML for 'Loading' message

Tags: html, loading

I'm working on a web app that requires content to load dynamically. While loading, the word "Loading" appears temporarily.

I want to place the word "Loading" into a semantic markup tag.

Is there a correct semantic tag for this?

Right now it's using H1 but I know that's not right.

Comment: You likely want to add the correct ARIA role - what that is though, I don't know.

Comment: It's definitely not a header. I think using a regular `<div>` or `<span>` is enough in this case.

Comment: `<Progress>` element makes sense here, but more so if you display actual progress

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `progress` element, with the ARIA role "progressbar". BUT:

- The bar renders slightly different in various browsers
- Some older browsers don't support it at all
- It may require additional markup for some browsers to display the text
- if you show a progress bar, you'll want it to... progress. Which means adding javascript

`<progress role="progressbar" value="70" max="100">loading...</progress>`

http://jsfiddle.net/t3sg2/2/

There is nothing inherently wrong with using an `h1`, or any other tag, really. You can assign the ARIA role to any tag.

**Documentation**

- `progress` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress
- ARIA progressbar role - http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#progressbar